# Draw a rectangle on canvas with center at touch point

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on the canvas with the center at the touch point. I'm using the following code:

```
canvas.drawRect((point.x + 15), (point.y + 15),(point.x + 15),(point.y + 15), paint);
```

But it doesn't work.

But when I use,

```
canvas.drawRect(point.x , point.y ,(point.x + 30),(point.y + 30), paint);
```

amazingly,it works. But the only harm is it is not centered at the touch coordinates.The top left of the rectangle coincides with the touch coordinates.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your x,y pairs are both

```
(point.x + 15), (point.y + 15)
```

You want the first pair to be

```
(point.x - 15), (point.y - 15)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first example was drawing a 1 pixel dot, which is why it looked like it didn't work.

To draw a 30px square at the point of contact, try this

```
canvas.drawRect(point.x - 15 , point.y - 15 , point.x + 15, point.y + 15, paint);
```

Comment: Sorry but I will have to accept the other answer as the correct answer,that person was quicker. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int rectWidth = 15;
int rectHeight = 15;

canvas.drawRect((point.x - rectWidth / 2), (point.y - rectHeight / 2),(point.x + rectWidth / 2),(point.y + rectHeight / 2), paint);
```